# Is there a simple way to check if cin input has a space?

Tags: c++

Say i have something like this `int s` and `cin >> s`.  Is there a simple way to test if user input for 's' is a white space without resorting to `isspace` which would result in first converting that int to a string and then back to an int again after my test.

Comment: "`isspace` which would result in first converting that int to a string" - no, it wouldn't, why do you think it does? anyway, **please** use `std::getline()` and `std::string::find()`.

Comment: well i mean using getline will capture it as a string won't it?

Comment: @ZeeZeeZee: Yes, and that's a good thing.

Comment: @ZeeZeeZee `getline` is neither `operator>>` nor `isspace`. I was referring to your assertion in your question: you stated that "using getline would result in first converting that int to a string and then back to an int", which is not the case.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant poor wording on my part.  I meant to say without getting a string and then converting to an int after the white space test.

Comment: @ZeeZeeZee Text input is inherently text. When you enter a number in decimal form, the I/O library takes it as text. If you want a number, you have to convert it. Doing so manually don't require *any* additional CPU or memory because the conversion would require it anyway (that's what `operator>>(int &)` does internally), you would just have access to the intermediate string. So, the short answer is "no, and you shouldn't need it either".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `std::getline` function to get a **whole line** of input as a `std::string`, then parse the line, which can be as easy as using [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) in C++11:

```
std::string input;
std::getline(input, input, std::cin);
int const s = std::stoi(input);
```

It will check the input for validity and throw an exception if no conversion can be performed. Additionally, having the input available as a `std::string`, you can perform any checking you like, and it's trivial to check the existence of a particular character in a string.

Comment: Thanks Christian, i hate the fact that my text book does not have `std::stoi`

Comment: @ZeeZeeZee: Well, `std::stoi` is a relatively new addition to C++.  Which also means that there are still environments where you cannot use it; a software company will not switch to a newer compiler version just for fun. Previously, you'd use something like `boost::lexical_cast`, or you'd directly use a `std::istringstream`.

Comment: Perhaps i won't use stoi then just to be safe.  My program is essentially going to ask a user for a number which it will use later.  My professor wants us to validate all white spaces as well.  I can use getline to capture the whole input then test for space and then test to see if the user has put a number in and if thats true i'd convert the string into a number and use it seems so silly.

Comment: @ZeeZeeZee: Your professor probably requires the code you hand in to run a particular compiler on a particular system. If that target system uses C++11, then there's no problem with `std::stoi`. If not, use `std::istringstream`. If the professor did not specify the target system, then that's a problem with the course IMO. (Way back, at my old university, the professor even provided a build server for us to upload and test our code before handing it in.)

Comment: You were lucky, there are several people in my class who are fed up with my professor.  IMO the worse thing a professor can do is not make things hard but rather not make what he expects crystal clear.  Anywho is there a reason why you made the `int s` a `const`?

Comment: @ZeeZeeZee: If made it `const` because it shows that with this approach you *can* do that, whereas you cannot with your original code. And my personal coding style tends towards making everything `const` unless I need to modify it (I actually wish variables were `const` by default, not the other way round).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64114/discussion-between-zeezeezee-and-christian-hackl).

Answer (score 1):

If you do:-

```
int s;
cin >> s;
```

It won't even return on entering whitespace. User has to enter some non-whitespace character.